# Why rspec is getting different results from similar console operations? (M. Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial 2ed - Section 6.3.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am having a problem with the RSpec tests for user model at the end of section 6.3.4 of M. Hartl's Rails tutorial. I am absolutely lost please help.

All of the tests are passing apart from one that I need help with:

*My question: Why rspec is getting different results from similar console operations and how can I fix this and pass the test?*

> Failures:
>
> 1) User return value of authenticate method with valid password
>
> Failure/Error: it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password)
>   }
>          expected: User id: 1, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: "2013-08-21 21:38:32", updated_at:
>   "2013-08-21 21:38:32", password_digest:
>   "$2a$04$tjcti4yEYFuJbbz9sa.Z9.F/KXJtHU3A8onU1Fhovn3x...">
>               got: #User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest:
>   "$2a$04$6fdtfzgCFYetjShfYKuFIObWo4Uru4xRMkhW7Ow92O.2...">
>
> Finished in 0.64049 seconds 20 examples, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:100 # User return value of
>   authenticate method with valid password

When I manually test it in rails console, authenticate method returns exactly the same user with all of the fields matching. Following is my console experiment:

> Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.0.0) Any
>   modifications you make will be rolled back on exit irb(main):001:0>
>
> **user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
>   password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")**
>
> => #
>
> irb(main):002:0> **user.save**
>   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1 User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE
>   LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('user@example.com') LIMIT 1 Binary data
>   inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
>
> SQL (48.2ms) 
>   INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest",
>   "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 21 Aug 2013
>   21:45:13 UTC +00:00], ["email", "user@example.com"], ["name", "Example
>   User"], ["password_digest",
>   "$2a$10$6tJCohmi7t3OShf/55S5Se98JWvGhJfC1wNAZsc8B6WPP1Zgee0wu"],
>   ["updated_at", Wed, 21 Aug 2013 21:45:13 UTC +00:00]]
>
> (0.2ms)RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
>   => true
>
> irb(main):003:0> **found_user = User.find_by_email(user.email)**
>
> User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'user@example.com' LIMIT 1
>   => #
>
> irb(main):004:0> **user == found_user.authenticate(user.password)**
>
> => true

This is what I have in spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") }

  subject { @user }
.
.
.

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end

.
.
.
end
```

User model is as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

end
```

Not sure if gem is important, here is what I have in mine:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Bootstrap css framework from Twitter
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'

# RSpec testing framework
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
```

Thank you in advance, please let me know if I missed out on any other important bits of info.

Comment: You might want to change your question title to "Why rspec is getting different results from similar console operations and how can I fix this and pass the test?", the current title isn't a question and doesn't make sense

Comment: You got a point there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem you're having is how you're setting up your tests.  The subject is being set as the unsaved instantiation of the object.  If you were to do a `before { subject.reload }` after your `@user.save` then it would fix this.  That's really just a bandaid.

The real problem is you're **over complicating** your spec. Your setting the same user in three different places in three different ways in three different states. This should never happen.

Here's how I'd set this up:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do    
  describe "#authenticate" do
    let(:user) { User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") }

    it "has a valid password" do
      user.authenticate("foobar").should be_true
    end

    it "has invalid password" do
      user.authenticate("invalid").should be_false
    end
  end
end
```

Just a couple of notes to keep in mind.

**Create as few objects as possible:** The more you create the more likely something isn't needed or is in a bad state and your tests fail or even worse your tests are fragile and fail unexpectedly.

**Single line `it` is fine, but limiting:** Single line `it` blocks are great when you need to do some quick validation, but you should use them sparingly. If you find that you're wrapping an `it` block in a `describe` then get rid of that `describe`

**Keep it simple:** Try not to front load your tests. When you front load more than likely you're writing tests that conform to the data.

There a bunch of other great tips over at http://betterspecs.org/. By no means take this as law, but it does have some good information on setting a really good foundation for writing specs.

Lastly, good luck and enjoy writing specs!

Comment: Thank you for a reply, I will play around with my tests and see what happens. Great link too, thanks for sharing it, I'd thumb-up your replay but my rep is still too low :(